# Microsoft ASP.net and Web Tools for Visual Studio 2015 contains virus detect by virustotal.com

Tags: visual-studio-2015, virus

When VS2015 starts, I got the update notification as snapshot below. Though, when download it from the [given link](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/4e40781f298ca541bab91168e75bcecd88cf325a854e7e77974ec8e84eee833c/analysis/1451778262/), then scanned by [virustotal.com](http://virustotal.com), I got [two viruses detected](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/4e40781f298ca541bab91168e75bcecd88cf325a854e7e77974ec8e84eee833c/analysis/1451778262/).

Is this true? Why contains viruses @@?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is a false positive. VirusTotal covers 50+ virus scanners. You need to see which ones are giving the positive.  You might want to contact them and submit the file for inspection.

EDIT: I see those 2 are  obscure virus checkers probably nothing to worry about. The Chinese one has ceased English support: http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/jiangmin-antivirus.377497/ , you might want to submit the file to the Ukrainian one http://zillya.com/suppor (not a typo)

The update should be digitally signed by Microsoft which should somewhat alleviate your concerns.

If you are really paranoid you might want to find hashes for that update and compare to what you download.

I am in charge of a software product which also reported 2/53 on VirusTotal. Simply doing a few minor revisions and then recompiling this software was enough to get rid of the virus warnings.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and clear response. Please update us once we have the new clean release. Thank you.

Comment: I'll do the hash check. Though, sending file to the Ukrain I guess not my side.